# @property failing, what's wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So, I have a class called Stone.
In **Stone.h** i have those lines:

```
@interface stone : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
GameLayer *theGame;
}
@property(readwrite,nonatomic, retain) GameLayer *theGame;
@property(readwrite,nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *mySprite;
```

and my **Stone.m**

```
@implementation Stone

@synthesize theGame,mySprite;
```

This is all relevant code. But the compiler says - no declaration of property theGame and mySprite found in the interface.
And to make it worse this is a book example, what am I doing wrong? I checked code it is exactly the same as in book.

Why is it not seeing the declaration of properties in .h file? #import statement is there.
I thought it was pointer issue, but it is not seeing properties for pure ints too - 
`@property(readwrite, assign) int stoneType;` for example returns same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lowercase 'stone' in your @interface, uppercase 'Stone' in your @implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Change 'stone' here:

```
@interface stone : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
GameLayer *theGame;
}
@property(readwrite,nonatomic, retain) GameLayer *theGame;
@property(readwrite,nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *mySprite;
```

To Stone:

```
@interface Stone : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
    GameLayer *theGame;
    }
    @property(readwrite,nonatomic, retain) GameLayer *theGame;
    @property(readwrite,nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *mySprite;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should write Stone (uppercase) after Interface.

Second, there is no variable "mySprite" in your interface.

Comment: With the modern runtime, no explicit variable declaration is needed for properties; they will be automatically synthesized. And as this question is tagged [iphone], the modern runtime is definitely applicable.

Comment: If using the modern Objective-C runtime (iOS 3.x + or 64-bit Snow Leopard onward) then when you @synthesize the property, the ivar will in effect also be synthesized for you.